# How to get first non empty filtered value from foreach PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array then i filtered the value and the result is null/empty.

How to determine first filtered value that non empty?

```
<?php

$items = array('a1a','bb2','o3e','two','three');

$i=0;

foreach($items as $item) {

    $item = str_replace('a1a','',$item); //filter remove
    $item = str_replace('bb2','',$item); //filter remove
    $item = str_replace('o3e','',$item); //filter remove

    //ITRY THIS BUT NOT WORK IF THE SECOND AND THIRD IS EMPTY/NULL TOO
    if($i==0) {
        if(empty($item)){
            //skip
        } else {
            //STATUS PUBLISH
        }

    } else { 
        //STATUS ATTACHMENT
    }

$i++;           
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question or show an expected output

Comment: `if(!empty($item)) { ..... do your stuff....` ?

Comment: i use that code but the problem is the second and third value is empty too, how to skip first, second, third and 'do something in fourth' as the first from foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get first non empty filtered value from foreach PHP?

If I understood correctly, you want the first item from they array `$items` that has not been emptied with your `str_replace`.

If this is correct, here is how to proceed:

```
<?php
$items = array('a1a','bb2','o3e','two','three');

$first = true;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $itemOriginal = $item;
    $item = str_replace(['a1a', 'bb2', 'o3e'] ,'',$item); //filter remove

    if(!empty($item) && $first == true){
        $first = false;
        echo "status publish -> ".$itemOriginal."\n";
    } else {
        echo "skip -> ".$itemOriginal."\n";
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
skip -> a1a
skip -> bb2
skip -> o3e
status publish -> two
skip -> three
```

If this is not what you want, please clarify your question and add a comment so I can look at it again.

**Update:**

> can value 'three' not skip? so i want to make wordpress publish using php from value foreach. the first value 'two' as publish and 'three' the next is as attachment

```
<?php
$items = array('a1a','bb2','o3e','two','three');

$first = true;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $itemOriginal = $item;
    $item = str_replace(['a1a', 'bb2', 'o3e'] ,'',$item); //filter remove

    if(!empty($item) && $first == true){
        $first = false;
        echo "status publish -> ".$itemOriginal."\n";
    } elseif(!empty($item)) {
        $first = false;
        echo "status attachment -> ".$itemOriginal."\n";
    } else {
        echo "skip -> ".$itemOriginal."\n";
    }
}
```

will output:

```
skip -> a1a
skip -> bb2
skip -> o3e
status publish -> two
status attachment -> three
```

Comment: can value 'three' not skip? so i want to make wordpress publish using php from value foreach. the first value 'two' as publish and 'three' the next is as attachment

Comment: Hi @sugiputra I added an update in my answer that does what you requested.